# Restcomm Connect USSD connected to OpenBTS over SIP

Tags: voip, gsm, ussd, restcomm, mobicents

I am trying to connect USSD connections OpenBTS to Restcomm-Connect over SIP. It seems like this should be possible but I keep running into issues.  Hopefully someone has done this before and can be of help.

**What I've Done So Far**

- OpenBTS is running and a phone can connect to the radio
- Restcomm Connect is running and I have created a USSD application
  to configured for *100# pointing to it.
- SIP.USSD.Proxy is pointing to the Restcomm SIP port

**What Happens When USSD Codes Are Dialed**

- A SIP INVITE goes to the Restcomm server. That looks like this

  INVITE sip:*100#;phone-context=irrelevant.net;user=dialstring@xxx.xx.x.xx:5080 SIP/2.0

  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <ussd-data>
       <language>en</language>
       <ussd-string>%s</ussd-string>
  </ussd-data>`

  - The Restcomm server then sends back a 400 Bad request.
  - A notification is left in the Restcomm logs.

    > Restcomm cannot process this call because the destination number *100#;phone-context=irrelevant.net;user=dialstringcannot be found or there is application attached to that

We have recompiled OpenBTS removing the line that adds the `;phone-context=irrelevant.net;user=dialstring` string [source](https://github.com/RangeNetworks/openbts/blob/master/SIP/SIPDialog.cpp#L809).  Thinking that it could be confusing Restcomm.  Still no luck.

One theory is that the OpenBTS SIP client needs to authenticate with Restcomm.

**Requirements**

- I am not beholden to Restcomm and would be fine with any OpenBTS -> SIP -> HTTP gateway.
- What is the reference implementation for OpenBTS USSD SIP?

Comment: what do you get in logs when you remove the `;phone-context=irrelevant.net;user=dialstring` ? Can you send the full INVITE that you receive at Restcomm Connect in that case ?

Comment: The new invite is INVITE sip:*100#@172.28.6.90:5080 SIP/2.0    The Content-Type is  application/vnd.3gpp.ussd+xml  The Restcomm notification error is the same but without the extra string.

Comment: We would need Restcomm Connect DEBUG logs to be able to investigate and tcpdump traffic on the Restcomm Connect machine.

Comment: After looking at this more it unfortunately seems that OpenBTS does not support USSD at the level we need to connect to RestComm.

Comment: @fizzyh2o - can you say why OpenBTS ended up not working for you?

did you try https://github.com/shingy92/ussd-openbts ? - it's a version of OpenBTS recompiled with some extra USSD support